# AngularJS: My scope variables update but my view does not. $apply, $timeout, $evalAsync do nothing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very large project that is in many pieces. I have tried to emulate the basic setup around this problem in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RkE6H/

Basically, I have a service that is called from controller A to create an object that is watched by controller B which is then picked up by a directive to create a select box in the view controlled by controller B. When the select value is changed, the directive should notify controller B, which calls a callback in the object, ultimately ending up back in controller A. (If that is super confusing, look at the jsfiddle... the scenario is replicated there)

Once I get called back in controller A, I make an $http call to get data which I shove into controller A's $scope. The data is in $scope.mydata at the end of everything, but the view controlled by controller A does not update.

I've tried running $scope.$apply (usually getting the warning that I'm already in the middle of a digest), wrapping various things in $timeout and $evalAsync, using $parse to do the callbacks instead of scope.callback, but nothing works. If that isn't bad enough, I tried to recreate a basic scenario for this in the jsfiddle above and the jsfiddle works fine.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I feel like it's related to the directive that makes the select box and how it's calling back or how the handler calls back, even though those actions are immediately preceded by an Angular event (ngChange).

```
scope.callback({
  e:{
    type:'selectChange',
    selectedItem:selectedItem
  },
  control:scope.control
});

select.callback.call($("#" + select.id).get(0), e, select);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

the problem with this is that if the service object is constructed at runtime in controller A but b tried to link to it before it existed he won't notice a change has happen, instead you can use getter functions to get your data or create an empty object in your service and then just extend it in your controllers that way you won't break the bindings

Comment: In my actual project, all Angular components are in separate files and loaded via RequireJS. The behavior I'm seeing is that my select box is created and has items in it; when I select an item, the callback in the controller is called and the callback requests data from a remote webservice using $http, then puts that data into a $scope variable, which had previously held data that is in the view, except after being updated, the view continues showing the old data. The problem is not specific to that one $scope variable. A simple string variable is also changed, but doesn't get updated.

Comment: the pattern remains the same
obj={name:'name'}
<input ng-model="obj.name"> shows the name
if you later do
obj={name:'othername'}
the input remains showing the name because you eliminated the object the model was bound to so you need either to rebind your element or to keep the original object ad extende it with the new data

Comment: After more digging, it looks like my Controller is getting loaded twice somehow (maybe related to how I'm doing routing?). For the time being (as a hack), I'm storing the $scope when the controller is created and comparing the $scope to the store one on event callback. If they don't match, I ignore the callback.

The current flow for whatever controller is attached to the route the app is opened on is 1) Controller is created, 2) $scope.$on('$destroy') gets called, 3) Controller gets created again.